# Natspec Commenting Style for Structs

Tags: solidity, struct, natspec

Is there  specific way to explain the variables of a struct using the Natspec format?
I do something like:

```
struct XYZ{
   uint x; //Explain what it does
   uint y;
}
```

Is it this the right way for structs, or like functions do we have to define the comment at the top?

Comment: Like functions.......

Comment: Looks like Compound is using [@member](https://github.com/compound-finance/compound-protocol/blob/v2.8.1/contracts/CTokenInterfaces.sol#L103-L107) to annotate struct fields, even if this is not a standard pattern (it's not found in the [NatSpec documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.2/natspec-format.html)).

Comment: Update: it looks like Solidity supports the [`@custom`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/natspec-format.html?highlight=%40custom#tags) directive now, which can be used for application-specific semantics

Answer (score 0):

How AAVE did it seems a bit inconsistent although, the code is understandable IMO.

```js
library DataTypes {
  // refer to the whitepaper, section 1.1 basic concepts for a formal description of these properties.
  struct ReserveData {
    //stores the reserve configuration
    ReserveConfigurationMap configuration;
    //the liquidity index. Expressed in ray
    uint128 liquidityIndex;
    //variable borrow index. Expressed in ray
    uint128 variableBorrowIndex;
    //the current supply rate. Expressed in ray
    uint128 currentLiquidityRate;
    //the current variable borrow rate. Expressed in ray
    uint128 currentVariableBorrowRate;
    //the current stable borrow rate. Expressed in ray
    uint128 currentStableBorrowRate;
    uint40 lastUpdateTimestamp;
    //tokens addresses
    address aTokenAddress;
    address stableDebtTokenAddress;
    address variableDebtTokenAddress;
    //address of the interest rate strategy
    address interestRateStrategyAddress;
    //the id of the reserve. Represents the position in the list of the active reserves
    uint8 id;
  }
```

https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/master/contracts/protocol/libraries/types/DataTypes.sol

They have 9 audits from some really big companies in the game with over a billion dollars within their protocol, so I would imagine they're doing something right

---

UniSwap-v3 also used a similar pattern:

```js
    struct Slot0 {
        // the current price
        uint160 sqrtPriceX96;
        // the current tick
        int24 tick;
        // the most-recently updated index of the observations array
        uint16 observationIndex;
        // the current maximum number of observations that are being stored
        uint16 observationCardinality;
        // the next maximum number of observations to store, triggered in observations.write
        uint16 observationCardinalityNext;
        // the current protocol fee as a percentage of the swap fee taken on withdrawal
        // represented as an integer denominator (1/x)%
        uint8 feeProtocol;
        // whether the pool is locked
        bool unlocked;
    }
```

https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/UniswapV3Pool.sol

---

Openzeppelin seems to follow a similar pattern as well:

```
struct Set {
        // Storage of set values
        bytes32[] _values;
        // Position of the value in the `values` array, plus 1 because index 0
        // means a value is not in the set.
        mapping(bytes32 => uint256) _indexes;
    }
```

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/structs/EnumerableSet.sol